# Closedness of a point evaluation operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a Banach space $X=L^p(0;1)$ and a subspace $Z=\{u \in W^{2,p}(0;1);u'(0)=0\}$, we define the operator $C:Z\to \mathbb{R}$ by $Cf=f(0)-f(1)$. Now i dont know if the operator $C$ is closed or not? Thanks for help.

Comment: it is closed. Just use the formula $f(1)-f(0)=\int _0 ^{1} f'(x) dx$ for $f \in W^{2,p}$.

Comment: Taking a sequence $(f_n) \subset Z$ such that $f_n \to f \in X$ and $Cf_n \to y$, i have to show that $f\in Z$ and $Cf=y$. I don't know how to use this formula to reach my goal.

Comment: Apply the formula for each $f_n$ and take limit.

Comment: Thank you for help, i get it now.